# python writerows: Error: iterable expected, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, list, csv, twitter, tweets

I am trying to save a list that contains tweets to a csv file. Here is my code:

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
all_tweets=[]
for page in Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=screen_name,count=5).pages(1):
    for status in page:
        outtweets = ([screen_name, status.created_at, status.text.encode('utf-8'),status.user.location, status.lang]) #for tweet in status]
        all_tweets.extend(outtweets)
        with open('tweets1_DB_SS.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(all_tweets)
```

I get the following error:

```
    ---> 12                 writer.writerows(all_tweets)

Error: iterable expected, not datetime.datetime
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You want to `append` not `extend` so you have a list of lists, not a plain list. And the writing to file should be done outside the *for* loop.